# How to watch air broadcasted TV with VLC Player on a Mac

Tags: vlc, television

I want to watch my air broadcasted TV with VLC Player on a Mac.

I have a standard European TV connection (free air-broadcasted TV), and I would guess I need some sort of USB TV tuner to connect the antenna cable to my Mac.

Can I just buy any USB TV tuner, or do I need to get anything specific?

Could you give me an example of device I need to buy? I'm not asking for suggestions about what to buy, but just an example to define the category.

Comment: How is it both "cable" and "air-broadcasted"? One precludes the other.

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder Let's be more pedantic :) Perhaps the *cable* being referred to isn't really meant as "cable TV", as in a paid-for programming service delivered into the domicile over a cable from outside, but rather a reference to the antenna device's cable.  Even antennas need to be connected to a TV or computer with a **cable**.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea He says, "I want to watch my cable TV." That doesn't sound like he means, "I want to watch TV using a cable that is connected to my TV antenna," to me.

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder But the OP also referred to "free air-broadcasted TV", which contradicts the kind of "cable TV" you're interpreting it to mean.  Yes, there's some confusion in the choice of words.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea My point exactly. :)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea The cable is connecting my antenna to the tv indeed. Ive updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any particular reason for needing to use VLC?
If you don't you could try EyeTV as it supports a good range of tuners (mine is a miglia) and has a streaming app for the iPhone / iPad

http://www.miglia.com/
http://www.elgato.com/

Elgato also do network aware tuners

Comment: Ps. Is appleTV a tv tuner as well?

Comment: So, I've bought EyeTV Hybrid from Elgato. It works, but the image is a bit pixelated, not very good quality, like on a normal TV. I've tried to unplug plugs cables, USB stick, restarting mac, etc, but it is the same. And in the settings I can see the strength of the signal is 100% and its' quality is between 90 and 95%

Answer (score 0):

No the apple TV isn't a tuner, just a media streaming device (the original one also had a hdd to store files)

Comment: Please remove this as an answer and add it as a comment to the above thread. Thank you!